# Rotating an Ellipse Anticlockwise

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

The quadratic equation $5x^2-6xy+5y^2+20 \sqrt{2}x -28 \sqrt{2}y + 72 = 0$ becomes $(5−3 \sin(2α))x'^2 + (5+3 \sin(2α)) y'^2 - 6\cos(2α)x'y' + 4\sqrt{2}(5\cos(α)-7\sin(α))x' - 4\sqrt{2}(5\sin(α)+7\cos(α))y'+72=0$

after applying the rotation $x=x'cos\alpha - y'\sin\alpha, y=x'\sin\alpha + y'\cos\alpha$.

Determine the type of the conic with equation above. Hence, determine, with respect to
the $x',y'$ -coordinate system, the coordinates of the center, focus (foci), vertex (vertices)
and where applicable asymptotes. Hence determine the coordinates of the focus (foci) in
the $x,y$ coordinate system.

Working: The $x'y'$ coefficient must be $0$, so $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}$. This gives after simplification $\frac{(x'-2)^2}{4} + \frac{(y'-3)^2}{1}=1$.

Type: Ellipse

Center: $(2,3)$

Foci: $(2 + \sqrt{3},3) , (2-\sqrt{3},3)$

Vertices: $(4,3) , (0,3)$

No asymptotes

In $x-y$ coordinate system, the foci are $(2+\sqrt{3},3),(2-\sqrt{3},3)$.

Are these correct. I am confused babout the meaning of the finding the things like foci and center in the $x',y'$ coordinate system. Is that basically the $x-y$ axis rotated $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians anticlockwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type: Ellipse
> Center: $(2,3)$
> Foci: $(2 + \sqrt{3},3) , (2-\sqrt{3},3)$
> Vertices: $(4,3) , (0,3)$
> No asymptotes

These are correct.

> In $x-y$ coordinate system, the foci are $(2+\sqrt{3},3),(2-\sqrt{3},3)$.

This is not correct. The foci are given by
$$x=(2\pm\sqrt 3)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-3\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{-\sqrt 2\pm\sqrt 6}{2}$$
$$y=(2\pm\sqrt 3)\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+3\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5\sqrt 2\pm\sqrt 6}{2}$$

What you did is as follows :

You rotated the ellipse $5x^2-6xy+5y^2+20 \sqrt{2}x -28 \sqrt{2}y + 72 = 0$ by $(-\frac{\pi}{4})$ **anticlockwise** (i.e., $\frac{\pi}{4}$ **clockwise**) around the origin, and got the ellipse $\frac{(x-2)^2}{4} + \frac{(y-3)^2}{1}=1$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5x%5E2-6xy%2B5y%5E2%2B20+sqrt%282%29x+-28+sqrt%282%29y+%2B+72+%3D+0+and+%28%28x-2%29%5E2%29%2F4+%2B+%28y-3%29%5E2%3D1+and+x%3D0+and+y%3D0).

---

In general, we can say the followings :

- If we rotate a point $(x,y)$ by $\color{red}{\theta}$ **anticlockwise** around the origin, then we get $(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$.
- If we rotate a curve $f(x,y)=0$ by $\color{red}{(-\theta)}$ **anticlockwise** (i.e., $\theta$ **clockwise**) around the origin, then we get a curve whose equation is $f(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)=0$.

---

**Added** :

You correctly got $\frac{(x'-2)^2}{4} + \frac{(y'-3)^2}{1}=1$.

In the $x',y'$ -coordinate system, we have, as you wrote

- Center: $(2,3)$
- Foci: $(2 + \sqrt{3},3) , (2-\sqrt{3},3)$
- Vertices: $(4,3) , (0,3)$

Then, you are asked to determine the coordinates of the foci in
the $x,y$ coordinate system.

This means that you are asked to determine the coordinates of the foci of the ellipse $$5x^2-6xy+5y^2+20 \sqrt{2}x -28 \sqrt{2}y + 72 = 0\tag1$$

As I wrote, the foci of $(1)$ are given by
$$x=(2\pm\sqrt 3)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-3\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{-\sqrt 2\pm\sqrt 6}{2}$$
$$y=(2\pm\sqrt 3)\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+3\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5\sqrt 2\pm\sqrt 6}{2}$$

This is because if we rotate a point $(x,y)$ by $\color{red}{\theta}$ **anticlockwise** around the origin, then we get $(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$.

In the similar way, we can see that the center and the vertices of the ellipse $(1)$ are as follows :

- Center : $(-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\frac{5\sqrt 2}{2})$
- Vertices : $(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, \frac{7\sqrt 2}{2}),(-\frac{3\sqrt 2}{2},\frac{3\sqrt 2}{2})$

---

You might want to see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5x%5E2-6xy%2B5y%5E2%2B20+sqrt%282%29x+-28+sqrt%282%29y+%2B+72+%3D+0+and+%28%28x-2%29%5E2%29%2F4+%2B+%28y-3%29%5E2%3D1+and+x%3D0+and+y%3D0) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5x%5E2-6xy%2B5y%5E2%2B20+sqrt%282%29x+-28+sqrt%282%29y+%2B+72+%3D+0++foci).

Comment: So are the center and vertices in both coordinate systems the same ?

Comment: I am not sure whether the foci in the $x-y$ coordinate system are correct? E.g., the point $(2,2)$ does not equal a distance $2a$ from the two foci added together. I am unsure why the coordinates of the foci aren't the same in both coordinate systems like the center and vertices ?

Comment: @Nikita Mazepin : I added some explanations.